# background-image not showing up on page

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to set a div's background to be some image, but for some reason it's not working. I'm pretty sure this is a noob error -- I just can't figure it out.

Here's my code (html first portion then css):

## H&S Displays

```
.title {
    background-image: url('/images/LOGO.jpg');
    //... other code
}
```

I have my file directory as follows:
FOLDER: images
FOLDER: css
index.html
FOLDER: pages

Comment: Remove the / at the start of the url

Answer (score 1):

try adding ".." before the "/images", might be that the css needs to go back a folder before accessing the images folder?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url)

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

Chris Coyier has a [brief explanation](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) of how this works out practically, but his visualization is pretty straight forward.

[image]

Beginning a CSS URL with '/' should return you to root, so mostly likely either your root is not what you think it is (ie, a higher parent directory than you realize) or your files are not organized like you think they are.

[Consult your console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#errors-and-warnings) and see where the error reports that it is looking for your image file. That should clue you in to what is wrong with your relative path.